# Boolean function and logic circuits

Tags: logic-gates, function, boolean-algebra

I have at my disposal: 2 input **AND** & **OR** logic gates and 1 input **NOT** logic gates.

I need to prove (or disprove) that:

1) Every Boolean function in **3 variables** (all 256 of them) can be represented in a logic circuit with **max of 10 logic gates** (AND, OR & NOT)

2) Every Boolean function in **n variables** (all \$2^{(2^n)}\$ of them) can be represented in a logic circuit with **max of \$3 \times 2^n\$ logic gates**

Where should I start from? Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This the full answer for the second one, so don't read the spoiler if you don't want everything yet.

You can do it by induction. We are going to prove that this is possible with \$5\times2^{n-1}-4\$ gates, and that this is better than \$3\times2^n\$ gates.

- You can realize any 1 variable logic circuit with 1 gates (a NOT gate, or not a NOT gate), and this is less or equal to \$5\times2^{1-1}-4=1\$.
- Assume that you can realize any \$n\$ variables function with \$5\times2^{n-1}-4\$ gates, noted \$F(n\ var)\$. You want to add a variable \$X\$. \$X\$ is either \$0\$ or \$1\$, so the following expression:

> \$[F_a(n\ var) AND (NOT\ X)] OR [(F_b(n\ var) AND\ X]\$

cover all possible functions. That function use the following number of gates:

> \$5\times2^{n-1}-4 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 5\times2^{n-1}-4 + 1 = 5\times2\times2^n-4 =5\times2^{(n+1)-1}-4\$ for all \$n\$ greater than \$0\$.

So this is true for \$n+1\$.

- By induction, the property is true for all \$n\$, so we can realize any function with \$5\times2^{n-1}-4\$ gates.
- Finally,
  \$3\times2^{n}=6\times2^{n-1} \gt 5\times2^{n-1} \gt 5\times2^{n-1}-4 \$ for all \$n\$ greater than \$0\$.

In a circuit point of view, you can see this solution as a pyramid of 2-input MUXs, with the first variable at the base all the first layer MUXs, and one row of MUXs by extra variables.

edit:formating

edit2: corrected math mistake, proving for \$5\times2^{n-1}-4\$ instead.

Comment: I have one question about the proof. How do you get 5×2^(n−1)−4+1+1+1+5×2^(n−1)−4+1, where are the 1+1+1 from?

Comment: To Antonio: the used gates are, from left to right:
\$5\times2^{n-1}-4\$ for \$F_a(n\ var)\$
+1 for a AND
+1 for a NOT
+1 for a OR
+\$5\times2^{n-1}-4\$ for \$F_b(n\ var)\$
+1 for another AND.

Comment: I don't see the logic using +1+1+1, why are we adding them? Is because of NOT X and just X?

Comment: The first expression (in the first spoiler) is the boolean expression itself. The second one (second spoiler) count the number of gates, so it's not boolean logic. Every gate used to make the first expression must be added to find the total number of gates.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one, you can try to make a worst possible case Karnaugh table.

> like \$\bar A*B*C + A*\bar B*C + A*B*\bar C + \bar A*\bar B*\bar C\$

---

> This function cannot be simplified anymore, but I don't have a formal proof. All factors are independent with each other. This expression require at least 3 NOTs, 8 ANDs and 3 ORs, so 14 gates.